# Restkit Response in text/xml

Tags: xml, restkit, mime-types

I have a WS that return a plist.
I am using Restkit and I would like to map the response.

So first I initilialize my ObjectManager like this:

```
sharedInstance.manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ROOT_URL]];
```

I accept the text/xml:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
```

And I launch my request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/foo/foo" parameters:nil];
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:[BddManager sharedInstance].manager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %d", result.count);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail!");
}];
[operation start];
```

Finally I get this error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"application/json"
)}, got text/xml,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using? v0.10 or v.20?

Comment: The last one: 0.20.0rc1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RestKit 0.20.0rc1 does not include an XML serializer in the main repository, but you can find one here: [RKXMLReaderSerialization](https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization).

Install via cocoapods: (or add the source files to your project)

```
pod 'RKXMLReaderSerialization', :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Import the header where you initialize RestKit.

```
#import "RKXMLReaderSerialization.h"
```

Finally, register the serialization class with RestKit. Insert this after you initialize the object manager and before you set the accept header.

```
sharedInstance.manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ROOT_URL]];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You'll need to tell the RKObjectManager how to handle the data that is being serialized after the loading process.

```
[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
```

**Edit:**

Just saw that your talking about a request but your using the method for sending an object to your WS via POST.

To get objects from the server, use the following method that is provided in the example applications of RestKit.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"yourPath" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // Success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Error
    RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I go the same error.
Furthermore this method is to serialize the request, I think my problem is to serialize the response, no?
However thank you